# Should I use lightttpd or nginx for an ubuntu VPS?

Tags: nginx, vps, ubuntu-10.04, lighttpd, openvz

I'm working on setting up a VPS, and I'm not about to go with slow apache. I'm looking into lighttpd and nginx, but I don't know which one to go with.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 on an OpenVZ VPS

My VPS has these resources:

- 40 GB disk space
- 1.5 GB memory/2 GB burst
- 3 TB bandwidth

Comment: Depends on your applications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer nginx over lighttpd for following reasons:

1. Easier and more sane config format.
2. More and better documented modules
3. It is actively maintained and developed. Last major release was 2 years ago.

Only pros of lighttpd over nginx
 1. Talking to backends via HTTP/1.1
 2. Automatic spawning of FastCGI backends

Comment: Alright. I think I'll try nginx, and see how I like it.